# i want to add default text in the Drop Down : zend framework

Tags: zend-framework

I want to add default text in the Drop Down:

Now I can get list data from database. But I can not set text default in Drop Down list data.

Code Example:

**zend_form**

```
$subject_level=new SubjectLevel();

$this->addElement('select','my_select',array(
            'label'=>'My select',
            'multioptions'=>$subject_level->getSubjectLevelList() // ok. data list from database
));
```

I want to show Drop Down output:

**show**

```
<option value="0" selected="selected">--- select please--- </option>  // default text not from database
<option value="1">class 1</option>
<option value="2">class 2</option>
<option value="3">class 3</option>
```

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
$this->getElement('select')->setValue(0);
```

will do fine.

Answer (score 0):

Value of first element in given array is default text for select.

```
$options = array_merge(array("default text"), $subject_level->getSubjectLevelList());
$this->addElement('select','my_select',array(
    'label'=>'My select',
    'multioptions'=>$options   
));
```